# How to open RAR file with Xarchiver?

Tags: rar

The file test.rar can be opened with `7z e  test.rar`.
When to double click on test.rar with Xarchiver,an error info occurs as following:

[image]

How can i add support for rar file with  Xarchiver ?

Comment: @Vlastimil Xarchiver is supposed to be able to handle RAR archives with `7z`.

Comment: Install the `p7zip-full` and the `p7zip-rar`

Comment: It is no ues to install  p7zip-full and the p7zip-rar ,double click same error info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install rar unrar
```

Once installed ,right click on the rar file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing 'unrar', that should work AFAIK.

If you're on Debian 'main' repos (only free-as-in-freedom packages) be advised that 'unrar-free' could have limited functionality. There's also 'unar' in that case.

Apparently this is the only official documentation: file:///usr/share/doc/xarchiver/index.html

You should have it if you have xarchiver installed.